# SQL - how to use SUBSRT or REEGEXP_LIKE in order to receive the surname of a person. For example Maria Anderson - I need just the Anderson. Thank you

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, select, substring

SQL - how to use SUBSTR or REGEXP_LIKE/REGEXP_REPLACE in order to receive the surname of a person. For example Maria Anderson - I need just the Anderson in the result. Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have something like `regexp_substr()` (in Oracle), you can do:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+$')
```

or using `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(name, '^.* ([^ ]+)$', '\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this using a regexp, or SUBSTR, because neither method knows anything about "names" or "surnames".

You can extract "*the last word of a string*", from the last space onwards (which in regexp is "the last nonspace sequence anchored to the $ end of the string": `\S+$` or `(.*\S)\s+(\S+)$`, so that "John De Beers" will give you a name of "John De" and a surname of "Beers".

The proper way of doing this would be to use a database of first names, and run a much more complex operation to extract matches. This will give you several unmatched names, and you will have to choose to either fall back to the "last word" method (which is *good enough*) or **manually** review why "Jhon Wilkes Booth" is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, you can use string functions for this:

```
select substr(name, instr(name, ' ') + 1)
```

`instr(name, ' ')` gives you the position of the first space in the string. THen `substr()` returns everything from the first following character to the end of the string.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=caa2b23ee4aacf8370b848a101e124bd)**:

```
with t as (select 'Maria Anderson' name)
select name, substr(name, instr(name, ' ') + 1) surname from t
```

```
name           | surname 
:------------- | :-------
Maria Anderson | Anderson
```